# How to update domainWideDelegation in "Service account details" of G-Suite Admin

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I want to enable domainWideDelegation of Service account details through api call.
I tried https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/patch
but it doesn't support domainWideDelegation parameter in payload.

Can anyone suggest, how to modify domainWideDelegation through api calls?

[refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE55p.png)